# Dynamically TreeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to create this logic for 2 days and even though on paper looks like a relatively simple problem, there are a lot of cases that mess this up while effectively writing the code.

After querying a web service, I receive this type of response:

[image]

I need to create a layout dynamically depending on the answer to simulate this behavior:

[image]

There is the main `spinner` that has all the root items. If I select one item there is 2 choices. If it doesn't have any children, I only add a textview. Otherwise I add a new spinner that has the children as options and if a children is selected, a new textview is created underneath. This goes recursively.

I successfully implemented this and it works **only** for 2 levels (the json presented without the id '5' element). I want this to work for an unlimited number of levels. The problem appears when i have a 3 level tree and i select on the middle node. I want to hide his edit text, but also the spinner and the edit text of his child and I don't have a direct access to the newly programmatically created views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive function. Stop recursion if child's node is empty. So you make first call on first item, if it have no children go next, if it have children call this function again.

Deleting view depends on root element you've selected. If it is `RecyclerView` then just update collection and notify adapter/use `DiffUtil` callback.
If you adding view dynamically then just set `View` id on creation and remove view by id on updates.

Comment: I'm adding views dynamically but you can't set an id programmatically on a view. Should I instead use **setTag**?

Comment: you can actually add id with setId() method

Comment: setId() doesn't work. It expects a resource type id.

Comment: @ZackKaytranada you're right. my bad. but yep u can try to do it with setting tag

Answer (score 1):

Set id to dynamically created view using  `View.generateViewId()` like `urview.setId(View.generateViewId())` and as per your need, remove them using id.